# Stop dropbox from starting on windows startup

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, window

I try to stop dropbox from running on windows 7 start up.

I went to dropbox configuration and opt this option out. pressed apply.

looked in cmd "msconfig" and this service wasn't there.

but yet it comes up everytime i run windows

Comment: Something is starting it.  Disable everything except what you need to boot the system to determine what needs to stay disabled.

Comment: there are lots of processes on msconfig. but all by "microsoft" as the "vendor" column says. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Is the DropBox program in your StartUp folder by chance? Location: "C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

Comment: @JoshR nop..it's empty

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays, there is a entry in the "Preferences" section, where you can control this:

[image]

Another option is to use [Starter](http://codestuff.obninsk.ru/products_starter.html), a Windows startup manager ... however, as noted above, the application (dropbox.exe) will re-add it on exit.

Comment: As the OP correctly noted, this option does nothing and does not solve the problem. Dropbox resists all ways to get rid of it that I know of (except maybe complete uninstall, I did not try this yet).

Comment: Well... probably this option only prevents from Dropbox welcome screen annoyance. But Dropbox is still running in the tray.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

1. Go to the Control Panel
2. Select Autoplay
3. Check if Dropbox is selected for Removable drive or Camera storage
4. In this case remove it and Save.

Answer (score 3):

Dropbox starts via shortcut in startup folder

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

[image]

remove the Dropbox.lnk here.

Comment: Nop. it's empty

Comment: for me it is there. Reinstall Dropbox and look if you now have the lnk file.

Comment: Dropbox will re-add the link on each quit unless you use Markus' solution (uncheck 'Start Dropbox on system startup').

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete the DropBox folder from C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming to stop this madness.